# Unable to set One plus bullets z2 neckband as both playback and speaker device

Tags: kde, bluetooth

In Nobara Linux 38 KDE, I cannot set my One Plus Bullets z2 neckband as the playback device and speaker/microphone. When I put the option as the default headset, my system does use the speaker of the neckband. Still, the incoming audio quality deteriorates, and any music becomes inaudible. When I set the option to High Fidelity Music, the incoming audio quality becomes smooth, but the system starts to use the built-in microphone/speaker.

I am sharing the screenshots for everyone's convenience.
This is when I set the option for One Plus Bullets Z2 to high-fidelity music.

[image]

This is when I set the option to Headset Head unit.

[image]

In the latter option, the system uses the headset's microphone, but the incoming audio quality is not convenient at all.

Is there any solution to this problem?